# Login with Facebook and Ionic 3 - Does not take me parameters to the other screen

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Does not take me parameters to the other screen

I am trying to get name and email, but it is not running, so the login runs me perfect.

I hope they can help me

The ionic version is as follows:

> cli packages: (C:\node\Ionic\taxilurin\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.6.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-utils                : 1.7.0
ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.7.0
```

> global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

> local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 browser 4.1.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Node : v6.11.2
OS   : Windows 10
npm  : 3.10.10
```

My code Home - Login:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
//Importamos los elementos que vamos a utlizar
import { RegistroCPage } from './../RegistroCorpotativo/registroC';
import { RegistroPPage } from './../registroParticular/registroP';
import { RegistroNPage } from './../registroNuevo/registroN';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  registroCPage = RegistroCPage;
  registroPPage = RegistroPPage;
  registroNPage = RegistroNPage;

  constructor(
    private facebook: Facebook,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public nativeStorage: NativeStorage
  ) {

  }

  loginFacebook() {
    this.facebook.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
      .then(rta => {
        console.log(rta.status);
        if (rta.status == 'connected') {
          this.getInfo();
        };
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  getInfo() {
    let nav = this.navCtrl;
    let env = this;
    this.facebook.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,picture,last_name,gender', ['public_profile', 'email'])
      .then(function (user) {
        env.nativeStorage.setItem('user',
          {
            name: user.name,
            gender: user.gender,
            picture: user.picture
          })
          .then(function () {
            nav.push(RegistroNPage);
          }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
}
```

My code de PostLogen:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook';
import { HomePage } from './../home/home';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-registroN',
    templateUrl: 'registroN.html'
})
export class RegistroNPage {

    user: any;
    userReady: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public fb: Facebook,
        public nativeStorage: NativeStorage) {

    }

    ionViewCanEnter() {
        let env = this;
        this.nativeStorage.getItem('user')
            .then(function (data) {
                env.user = {
                    name: data.name,
                    gender: data.gender,
                    email: data.email,
                    picture: data.picture
                };
                env.userReady = true;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    doFbLogout() {
        var nav = this.navCtrl;
        let env = this;
        this.fb.logout()
            .then(function (response) {
                //user logged out so we will remove him from the NativeStorage
                env.nativeStorage.remove('user');
                nav.push(HomePage);
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: ionViewCanEnter() should return a boolean to know if Page can be pushed or not.

Comment: I'm running it on my android emulator, I do not even get an error :c

Comment: @Ramon-san What was missing from my code?

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores in ionViewCanEnter() put return before this.nativeStorage.getItem('user'), and return true inside then bloc, and return false inside error block.

Answer (score 0):

`ionViewCanEnter()` method evaluates if router should push page into navigation stack or not. This method should return a boolean (or a Promise of boolean) to do this evaluation.

You actually did not returning a value, so that function is returning `undefined` and evaluate always as false, so Page can not be entered.

Make this small changes to code to return proper value:

```
ionViewCanEnter() {
    let env = this;
    return this.nativeStorage.getItem('user')
        .then(function (data) {
            env.user = {
                name: data.name,
                gender: data.gender,
                email: data.email,
                picture: data.picture
            };
            env.userReady = true;
            return true;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return false;
        });
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but as I realize that lign me devuleve something, where I apply my console or alert, since I'm defending I'm running in the emulator

Comment: If you are runing in emulator, plugins of Ionic Native and other Cordova plugins will not work. You need to test on a real device or create mock classes to simulate device respones. [Using Ionic Native on browser](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/browser.html)